# unique values out of two files

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, sed

i have two separate files, from which i need to make a new one, which has the unique values out of the two files.

Example:
File A:

```
1234567890123456720100603104500 Random text or data.
2345678901234567820100602104500 [New] Random Text.
3456789012345678920100509213849 Earlier \Date.
4567890123456789020100521195058 & InBetween Date
```

File B:

```
    1234567890123456720100603104500 Random text or data altered.
    2345678901234567820100602104500 [New] Random Text.
    3456789012345678920100509213849 Earlier \Date.
    4567890123456789020100521195058 & InBetween Date
```

Output:

```
    1234567890123456720100603104500 Random text or data.
    1234567890123456720100603104500 Random text or data altered.       
    2345678901234567820100602104500 [New] Random Text.
    3456789012345678920100509213849 Earlier \Date.
    4567890123456789020100521195058 & InBetween Date
```

sort -u does the job when it has to do with one file, but what when we have two, three, etc files? I would also appreciate implementation with sed and awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort` accepts multiple files.  Simply run `sort -u FILE1 FILE2 ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this output with these command line:

```
cat A B | sort | uniq > OutPut
```

You need to sort the lines and then delete the duplicated lines and store the output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `sort FileA FileB | uniq` or `sort -u FileA FileB`

Answer (score 1):

Following may also help you in same.

```
paste -d"\n" fileA fileB | uniq
```